# Chain promises in class without using .then

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, es6-class

This is part of a larger problem, but how could I chain method calls on a class when they require a `promise` to resolve in order to get data.

The following will not work as when `this.promise` is being assigned each time, the function has already returned with `this`

```
class Test {
  constructor(promise) {
    this.promise = promise;
  }

  add(x) {
    this.promise.then(y => {
      this.promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(x + y);
      });
    });
    return this;
  }

  multiply(x) {
    this.promise.then(y => {
      this.promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(x * y);
      });
    });
    return this;
  }

  answer() {
    this.promise.then(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });
  }
}

function getNumber(num) {
 const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
   resolve(num);
 });
 return new Test(promise);
}

const num = getNumber(30);
num.add(20).multiply(2).answer();  // Outputs 33 instead of 100: (30 + 20) * 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reassign the result of `then` (which is another promise) to `this.promise` in the methods. This will ensure the `this.promise` is always the latest promise in the chain.

```js
class Test {
    constructor(promise) {
      this.promise = promise;
    }
  
    add(x) {
      const promise = this.promise.then(num => num + x)
      return new Test(promise);
    }
  
    multiply(x) {
      const promise = this.promise.then(num =>  x * num)
      return new Test(promise);
    }
  
    answer() {
      this.promise.then(console.log)
    }
  }
  
  function getNumber(num) {
   const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
     resolve(num);
   });
   return new Test(promise);
  }
  
  const num = getNumber(30);
  num.add(20).multiply(2).answer();  // Outputs 100: (30 + 20) * 2
  num.add(5).multiply(3).answer();  // Outputs 105: (30 + 5) * 3
```

Comment: Great, that is a good step in the right direction. Something I didn't explain fully is I would need it to be immutable. So if we run `num.add(5).multiply(3).answer();` at the end, it won't start from `30`. It will now start from the last number

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid reassigning `this.promise`. I wouldn't make that a member of your class. You should just have your methods return the promise.

If you want to avoid using `.then`, look at using `async`/`await`.

Comment: The purpose is to chain function calls like many libraries do, such as rxjs. `num.add(20).multiply(2).answer();` would become very messy if after every function call you had to handle `then`

Comment: @tic have a look at async/await.

Comment: Async/await is not part of the es6 spec and causes so many coding problems. Every function now has to become async, and it assumes that every call succeeds, so we have to wrap every call with a try/catch

Comment: @tic `such as rxjs` -- if you are familiar with rxjs then I think you need to be aware of a higher level understanding of async design patterns. Promise is just one design pattern, one which rxjs rejects and does not use. What rxjs implements is an event stream (look at the stream interface in nodejs) which is another async design pattern. Rxjs is a bit more elegant because it structures events as monads (something which some people argued promises should implement before the spec was agreed upon by the community). Rxjs actually has something similar to promises: the `.once()` method